# scan partition for bad blocks

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, bad-sectors

I have a hard disk with bad sectors on it. I want to partition the drive so that the partitions are in the good part of the hard disk, and the parts that have bad sectors are not used.
The first ~20GB of the hard disk are good. Then comes a ~13GB part that is riddled with bad sectors. After that, the hard disk is good again, but at the very end there is a ~2GB part with bad sectors.
I have used an app called "Hdtune" to get this information, and I have created a 19GB c: partition at the beginning of the drive, then skipping the 13GB of bad sectors, then creating the D: partition that spans the rest of the disk, minus the last 2GB.

The C: partition works well (i have been using it for a month and i have got no error whatsoever), but the D partition has been giving me problems. Somehow, it seems that I have some bad sectors in the D: partition.

I am looking for an app that scans the HDD, finds the bad blocks, and shows them in a map so I can see if they are in the D partition. Or, an app that scans only a specified partition for bad sectors, and then shows in a map where the bad sectors are in the partition.
I want to know this so I can resize the D partition so that it is outside of the bad area of the disk.

Comment: Don't be mad at me but what about getting a new HDD instead of balancing on a tight rope in the air?

Comment: I will in the near future, but right now, I need to use this bad one.
I'm just looking for an app that can tell me how to resize the partitions so that that they won't have bad sectors

Comment: And if a new bad sector pops up? You resize everything again and add a new partition? Nonsense. You should use a proper tool that avoids blocks marked as bad.

Comment: Lo'oris: Do you have a suggestion for such a tool?

Comment: What about using `chkdsk` ? win+r: `cmd` . type: `chkdsk /?` . And you will see your options.

Comment: chkdsk does not tell me where the bad sectors are, so I don't know how much to resize the disk

Comment: If you add the bad sectors to the list, the HDD/OS wont use it. No point in this create/dont create method. (Or make it list the bad blocks and create partition setup with the data , using blocks as limits.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a great app called Partition Wizard. It allows me to do a surface scan on a single partition (not the whole drive) and I can see a map of that partition.
I have scanned my D partition, and I have seen that at 98% I got bad sectors. So I shrunk the partition by 1 GB, and now I can use it with (relative) confidence :)